# How to connect to IBM DB2 datasource using VBA in Excel 64bit

Tags: excel, vba, db2, 64-bit

My company plans to migrate from MS Office 365 32bit to the 64bit equivalent. I have developed a tool in Excel that connects to an IBM DB2 (and a MySQL data source, too).
This tool worked perfectly since years through different WinOS (XP/7/10 no matter if 32 or 64 bit) on different 32bit MS Office versions (XP, 2007,2013 and 365Pro).
But when running the tool on MS Office 365Pro 64bit, I'm struggling on the connection to the database (all other hurdles, e.g. the PtrSafe Declares are solved). I installed a 64bit version of the ODBC IBM DB2 client and configured this one in SysWoW64\ODBCAD and a connection test returns successfully. Insofar I assume at least the driver being ok.
When calling to open the connection in VBA, I always get the following error message:

[image]

To me, it looks that somehow Excel doesn't recognize the DB2 driver ->registration issue?
Here's my code:

```
Option Explicit

Public oDB2Connection As ADODB.Connection
Public zQuery As String
Public zDB2User As String
Public zDB2Pwd As String
Public oRecordSet As ADODB.Recordset

Public iLoginTrials As Integer
Public zTable As String

Sub ConnectDB2()
Dim PS As stPositions
Dim bFirstLogin As Boolean
Dim zStr As String

'//create connection object
Set oDB2Connection = New ADODB.Connection
Set oRecordSet = New ADODB.Recordset


On Error GoTo Errorhandler

iLoginTrials = 0
bFirstLogin = False

With oDB2Connection
    While (.State = 0)
        If (.State = 0) Then
            zDB2User = oMainSheet.Range(RANGE_DB_USR).Value
            zDB2Pwd = oMainSheet.Range(RANGE_DB_PWD).Value
        
            If (AccessLevel < AL_RO) Then
                bFirstLogin = True
                
                With DlgLogin
                    .LoginReadOnly.Visible = True
                    .LoginPM.Visible = True
                    .LoginAdmin.Visible = True
                    .LoginReadOnly.Value = 1
                    .UserName = USER_RO
                    .Password = "member"
                    
                    .StartUpPosition = 1 'posCenterOwner
        
                    PS = PositionForm(WhatForm:=DlgCalendar, AnchorRange:=ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1))
                    .Top = PS.FrmTop   ' set the Top position of the form
                    .Left = PS.FrmLeft ' set the Left position of the form
                    .Show '//RunUserInterface
                End With
            End If
        End If
                
      
        .ConnectionString = "Driver={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};" _
            & "Database=<myDB>;" _
            & "Hostname=<myHost>;" _
            & "Port=<myPort>;" _
            & "Protocol=TCPIP;" _
            & "Uid=" & zDB2User & ";" _
            & "Pwd=" & zDB2Pwd & ";"
    
        '//set cursor location
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    
        '//open database
        .Open
            
        zQuery = "SET CURRENT SCHEMA = 'DCODB2'"
        Message zQuery
        .Execute zQuery, , adExecuteNoRecords
        
        If (.State = 1) Then
            With oMainSheet
                .Unprotect ("*")
                .Range(RANGE_DB_USR).Value = zDB2User
                .Range(RANGE_DB_PWD).Value = zDB2Pwd
                .Protect ("*")
            End With
        End If
        
        '//in case of failure try again to login
        PP iLoginTrials
        If (iLoginTrials > 3) Then
            zStr = "Access to PM database denied"
            MsgBox zStr
            Message zStr
            End
        End If
    Wend '//.State = 0
    
    If (.State And bFirstLogin) Then
        ShowDlgDone "Connection to DB2 successfully established", vbModal
        Message "Userlevel: " & zDB2User
    End If
End With '//oDB2Connection

Exit Sub
    
    
Errorhandler:
    zDB2Pwd = ""
    With oMainSheet
        .Unprotect ("*")
        .Range(RANGE_DB_USR).Value = ""
        .Range(RANGE_DB_PWD).Value = zDB2Pwd
        .Protect ("*")
    End With
    
    MsgBox "Error: " & ERR.Description
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

A similar construct for the connection to MySQL also fails for 64 bit Excel.

Comment: For confidentiality reasons I replaced the connection parameters. In the original code, I don't use the "<>"...

Answer (score 0):

I found it out on my own!
Looking into the registry on
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers,
I saw there the name of the driver looking slightly different:
"IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - IBMDBCL1"

In my code I originally wrote:
"IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER"

So with the above fix I got it working, hurray!!